# swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Function not implemented When enabling swap

Tags: linux, debian, swap

I tried to enable swap according to this website: https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

When I ran `sudo swapon /swapfile`, it returned this error:

`swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Function not implemented`

Comment: What does `zgrep CONFIG_HIBERNATION /proc/config.gz` say?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk I ran it and it doesn't say anything

Comment: Are you running this commands on the real hardware or a shared hosting or something? From looking at the code of `util-linu` and `kernel/power/hibernate.c` it looks that hibernation is not enabled in the kernel.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I'm running it on the built-in Linux Crostini in ChromeOS

Answer (score 2):

It looks like CONFIG_SWAP is not enabled in the kernel you are using.
Please enable it and try.